# How to write python code batch convert json to html?

Tags: python, json, converters, json2html

I have 300 + json files.

The structure is like this:

```
{
  "body_html": "<div><head></head><body><div class=\"lake-content-editor-core lake-engine lake-typography-traditional\" data-lake-element=\"root\"><p id=\"a596b3f2-13d2-4a99-a3c2-5e0952e0b600\" style=\"font-size: 14px; color: rgb(38, 38, 38); line-height: 1.74; letter-spacing: 0.05em; outline-style: none; overflow-wrap: break-word; margin: 0px;\"><a href=\"https://ideas.darden.virginia.edu/the-power-of-an-idea-meritocracy\" target=\"_blank\">https://ideas.darden.virginia.edu/the-power-of-an-idea-meritocracy</a></p><p style=\"font-size: 14px; color: rgb(38, 38, 38); line-height: 1.74; letter-spacing: 0.05em; outline-style: none; overflow-wrap: break-word; margin: 0px;\"><br></p><p id=\"a596b3f2-13d2-4a99-a3c2-5e0952e0b600\" style=\"font-size: 14px; color: rgb(38, 38, 38); line-height: 1.74; letter-spacing: 0.05em; outline-style: none; overflow-wrap: break-word; margin: 0px;\">if you want to hire great people and have them stay working for you. you have to let them make a lot of decisions , and<mark> You have to be run by ideas, not hierarchy. the best ideas have to win , otherwise good people don&apos;t stay</mark>  <a href=\"https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&amp;ei=XxREXteKHZWe4-EP7t204Aw&amp;q=idea+meritocracy&amp;oq=ideameritocracy&amp;gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i10l4.870029.873986..875653...0.2..0.273.273.2-1......1....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.4KOME2IXHps\" target=\"_blank\">#ideameritocracy</a></p><p id=\"0798738b-9fb5-4ff3-9ff8-b6e395dd642b\" style=\"font-size: 14px; color: rgb(38, 38, 38); line-height: 1.74; letter-spacing: 0.05em; outline-style: none; overflow-wrap: break-word; margin: 0px;\">To be successful you need to pick product ideas based on their own merit (idea meritocracy) rather than on the basis of who thinks they are good (people meritocracy).</p><p id=\"949045a7-6b18-4fdf-af54-661dab3fca07\" style=\"font-size: 14px; color: rgb(38, 38, 38); line-height: 1.74; letter-spacing: 0.05em; outline-style: none; overflow-wrap: break-word; margin: 0px;\"><mark>An Idea Meritocracy is an environment in which the best idea wins</mark>. \n<mark>The best idea is determined by the quantity and quality of the data, not by positional power</mark>. \nI have studied examples of companies that have created Idea Meritocracies, including Google, Intuit, Pixar Animation Studios and Bridgewater Associates. In those organizations, an Idea Meritocracy has played a key role in driving consistent high performance and has warded off complacency and group think by empowering employees to have the curiosity and courage to challenge, to explore like scientists by asking the <mark>3 W</mark>&#x2019;s: <mark>Why ? What if ? Why not ?</mark></p><blockquote style=\"padding-left: 1em; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 0px; border-left: 3px solid rgb(238, 238, 238); opacity: 0.6;\">To flourish in the innovation age, companies must change how decisions are made and change how leaders lead. To do so you must change how decisions are made to what I call leadership by experiment. Moving from politics and PowerPoints to enabling the idea to prove itself. From boss votes with their opinion, to the customers vote with their feet. From the hierarchy sets the agenda, to the innovators set the agenda.</blockquote></div></body></div>",
  "slug": 4710687,
  "title": "Idea Meritocracy"
}
```

How to write python code batch convert json to html ?

The html file name is "title". such as "Idea Meritocracy".

Sample json file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dbnzvb99wrm0v0/json%20file%20-kangland.zip?dl=0

Sorry : I'm not a coder, I just to understand the code logic, but I can't write the code.

Thank you so much !

Comment: https://github.com/softvar/json2html

Comment: Post the code. What did you try? What did you get? What did you want?

Comment: All due respect, do you have any attempt or effort to achieve this? If so, could you please share with us?

Comment: I'm not coder, I just to understand the code logic, but I can't write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

list_of_files = ["kiqgfg.json"]
for file_name in list_of_files:
    fi = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = json.load(fi)
    fo = open(data["title"]+".html", 'w') 
    fo.write(data["body_html"])
    fi.close()
    fo.close()
```

It takes each file and takes data to write to a new html file.

If you need to read all the json files in a particular directory, use the below code. *edit: Added key check in json file*

```
import json
from glob import glob
for file_name in glob("*.json"):
    fi = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = json.load(fi)
    if 'title' in data.keys():
        fo = open(data["title"], 'w')
        if 'body_html' in data.keys():
            fo.write(data["body_html"])
    fi.close()
    fo.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! How to scan all json file ?

Comment: @Kanglando Add the file names in the `list_of_files`, i.e. list_of_files = ["file1.json", "file2.json", "file3.json"]. If the files exits in different paths, then add the full path.

Comment: all json files are in the same folder .  Is it possbile scan [*.json]  in a directory ?? @vivek-kumar

Comment: Please check the updated answer. It uses a `glob` library.

Comment: There's an error: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None` . But I add `str()` , `fo.write(str(data["body_html"]))`, still have error:  `File ".\json2html.py", line 26, in <module>`
   `fo = open(data["title"],'w')`
`KeyError: 'title' `

Comment: This error probably means that `title` key doesn't exist in the json file. There should be a condition to check if  key exists. I will edit the answer

Comment: Thank you so much ! I found that file, only one . I deleted it. But there's another problem have to be sloved first.  Title have special characters  ?  :  , etc. `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` .  I have to replaced those title.

Comment: I use re for replace special characters  `dataTitle = re.sub("[|\^&+\-%*?/=!>]", " ", data["title"])` , but got error : `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` 

@vivek-kumar

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**

```
pip install json2html
```

**Step 2 :**

```
from json2html import *
```

You can read individual JSON in your directory and pass that in for loop, for now, I have taken a single JSON.

```
sample = {
  "body_html": "<div><head></head><body><div class=\"lake-content-editor-core lake-engine\" data-lake-element=\"root\" data-selection...........}

json2html.convert(json = sample)
```

✅  Your output will look like this :

[image: output]